# Did title wrapping change? What is El ectron?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

The rocket formerly know as Electron has a new name, *El ectron.*

Am I imagining things, or did the wrapping of question title change in the edit window?

I thought it always did compete word wrap until recently. Am I mistaken?

> [image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318655/154443

Comment: Artist's Impression; https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I1R0.png

Comment: @RoryAlsop yep that seems to be it, a side effect of [a different fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318655/on-sites-with-new-responsive-theme-word-wrap-on-long-titles-breaks-in-the-middl#comment1044680_318655) perhaps. Thanks!